# Webpack SCSS and Babel config problems

Tags: webpack, sass, babeljs

Happy Holidays!

I have been struggling to set up a basic Webpack generated static site to do the following:

1. Minimize my HTML
2. Compile SCSS and minimize my css
3. Run my JS through Babel and minimize it
4. Eventually, optimize images

I reallize I can use Jekyll, Next, Gabspy, etc, but I want to learn Webpack and "roll my own".

Here is my [Webpack config](https://github.com/WebRuin/The-Classic-Lunchbox/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

The structure of my project is as follows...

```
Root
   src
      js
         ...
      scss
         ...
   dist
webpack.cong.js
app.js
```

My app.js file is simple:

```
import "./src/js/main.js";
import "./src/scss/style.scss";
```

I am have a few problems.  First, I can' figure out here my bundle.js files, min CSS files, min html files are being exported to.  I don't know were in the webpack config to specify here to export those files.

As a result, my css, which is strangely working despite a `404 error` for the css an bundle.js files.

Can y'all please help me?

Comment: Just to be clear, your problem is that your CSS and JS files are not generated? From what I see in your config you have 2 directories, publicPath and path, have you checked in both?

Comment: Also, do you get any error output when you run your process in console?

Comment: When you say "checked in", are you refering to git?

Comment: The resource from “http://localhost:4444/dist/bundle.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
localhost:4444
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:4444/dist/bundle.js”.

Comment: As far as I can see, the bundle.js is not being generated

Comment: No, with checked in I refer as if you opened the folder in your file explorer :) Is the file present there either in / or in /dist ? Does the CSS file get generated? When you run your process in command line does it show any errors?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Qppv08d

Comment: No.  The file is not generated

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your working directory? What happens if you try to open `http://localhost:4444/dist/bundle.js`? Because it's not an error 404 from what I see in your console screenshot

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6Gs0Cmr

Comment: "
Do you have a screenshot of your working directory? What happens if you try to open http://localhost:4444/dist/bundle.js? Because it's not an error 404 from what I see in your console screenshot" `Cannot GET /dist/bundle.js`

Comment: The screenshot above is the same as your previous. I meant the folder in your file explorer in the dist folder specifically.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/P0je0D3   it is being generated somewhere

Comment: Could you screenshot your `/home/tithos/Web Projects/pbj/dist` in your OS's file explorer?

Comment: "I meant the folder in your file explorer in the dist folder specifically." This is what is is strange... I can't fing the generated files anywhere.  my thought is `webpack-dev-server` is the problem

Comment: What is your OS? From what I see it's most likely a directory definition issue, the files are being generated maybe at the root of your system or the root of your folder.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/12FdIMU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204909/discussion-between-tithos-and-mihail-minkov).

Comment: This might be a wild guess, but can you try stopping your process, creating a `dist` folder in the root of your project and run your process again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Webpack config is fine. The problem is in the index.html template file you are using: the `src` for the js bundle, `dist/bundle.js`, is incorrect.

Since the index.html file is loaded from within the `dist` folder, the src to the JS bundle, which will also be located with the same folder, should be something like `/bundle.js` or `./bundle.js`.

Another way to solve this would be to remove the hard-coded script tag in the template file altogether and instruct `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, which will know the correct src to use, to inject the bundle:

```html
<!-- src/index.html -->

<!-- delete this -->
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

```js
// webpack.config.js

// add this:
// ...

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: SRC_DIR + "/index.html",
  inject: 'head'
}),
```